# Session timeout doesn't work for FBA sites - sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

We have a new Sharepoint Server which uses Sharepoint Server 2010. It runs on Windows Server 2008.

We are using it as a Webserver and need to deploy a timeout for all users who access it for security purposes.

Currently it is configured to use Windows Based Authentication on port 80 although we have tried to change this and set up a Form Based Authentication (FBA) site on different port and set the timeout settings for this also but it does not work.

We have tried using the timeout features of IIS and Sharepoint itself with a FBA setup and the user account still does not time out as required.

We are using FBA with LDAP environments.

Any help would be appreciated.

Note: We have visited the following link for solution but we don't know if we have a April 2011 Update installed on our sharepoint server as we are on SP2010 Build Version 14.0.6137.5002

http://jasear.wordpress.com/2011/01/10/sharepoint-2010-set-session-timout-on-a-fba-enabled-site/

Comment: You can kill the session with FBA using Request.Cookes.Remove() I believe will sign you out completely. Have you tried using this to close the session of the user or setting the expiry on the cookie?

Comment: Where do i need to use Request.Cookes.Remove() method? We want session to be timed out if user is in active for 20 mins.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried with:

```
$sts = Get-SPSecurityTokenServiceConfig
$sts.FormsTokenLifeTime = (New-TimeSpan -minutes 30)
$sts.Update()
Get-SPSecurityTokenServiceConfig
```

That will set up your web.config with the proper values, because if you are using WIF, you should be looking at "CookieHandlerElement", not "forms" tag.

Answer (score 1):

The point you need to set is the timeout value for your cookie in your forms configuration of your web config. Once expired the user will be logged out. Timeout is in minutes.

Hope this is enough for what you are looking for.

```
<authentication mode="Forms" >
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/SignIn" timeout="1200" cookieless="UseCookies" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: I have tried your solution but no success

Comment: Does session timeout work on local domain? I am testing FBA website on our local domain.

Comment: We are using FBA with LDAP environments.

Comment: Is timeout = 20 mins or 1200 sec? as per msdn i think it should be set to mins http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: You are right sorry I presumed seconds "Specifies the amount of time, in integer minutes"

Comment: I am just reading this following article on msdn  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147183
1) Does it apply to my environment FBA with LDAP?
2) Is it worth using 

$sts = Get-SPSecurityTokenServiceConfig
$sts.UseSessionCookies = $true
$sts.Update()
iisreset

Comment: Depends on what provider/how your authentication portal is configured if this would be supported. This is something I can't really help with. But it doesn't hurt to try if you have a test environment.

Comment: We just like to achieve idle session timeout under FBA with LDAP environment. I was expecting this to be very simple and straight forward but don’t why it is not working. Should i post my web.config file of website.

Comment: More information about the whole FBA would be required, ie the portal vendor, if its custom etc etc, but basically it just needs the session cookies expiring after 20 minutes. This should be straight forward... But how many times have I said that about SP ;) Post as much detail as possible, the auth section of your webconfig and web app settings as well. Did you deactivate and reactivate your auth provider btw after config changes? If you don't settings wont apply.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9227/discussion-between-user1263981-and-hugh-wood)